# Module Views automatically replace underscores in css classname to hyphens?

Tags: views, theming

The situation is like this: I created an article list block with Views, and I want give the list row a custom css classname, ex it's called "focus_img", but when I saw the output, "focus_img" was converted to "focus-img" automatically. How can I turn off this annoying feature? I don't get it, why it made this change, I just need it output what I want..

Comment: How are you adding a custom class to each row?

Comment: At Views editing interface, "setting" besides "list format"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design... Views module is cleaning class in views_plugin_style.inc..

```
  /**
   * Return the token replaced row class for the specified row.
   */
  function get_row_class($row_index) {
    if ($this->uses_row_class()) {
      $class = $this->options['row_class'];
      if ($this->uses_fields() && $this->view->field) {
        $class = strip_tags($this->tokenize_value($class, $row_index));
      }

      $classes = explode(' ', $class);
      foreach ($classes as &$class) {
        $class = drupal_clean_css_identifier($class);
      }
      return implode(' ', $classes);
    }
  }
```

Below statement is converting _ (Underscore) to - (hyphens)

```
$class = drupal_clean_css_identifier($class);
```

If you see documentation of [drupal_clean_css_identifier](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7) by default filters replaces _ with -.

Comment: `drupal_clean_css_identifier()` lists `underscore` as a **valid** character, though. So that can't be right ;)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't see the first lines...

Comment: thx man, but when I use block, give block a classname, it hasn't been changed, just stay what value I gave to it. I think this is a little tricky, too hard to find where get wrong..

Comment: Agree with you clive...  It's a views module issue.. They should send empty array or give some sort of settings for this.. It's already reported in issue queue here.. https://drupal.org/node/1111258 .. hope we will have fix soon..